# Encoding problem classic ASP

Tags: encoding, character-encoding, asp-classic

I have a problem with classic ASP. The encoding is wrong when I send data with `XMLHttp.send`. The response is a PDF file, but the “ÆØÅ” gets wrong, the “Ø” is read as “Ã¸y”  for example. It’s like it’s a converting mistake from UTF-8 to ISO-8859-1, but it should be  ISO-8859-1 now. I have `<%@CODEPAGE="28591"%>` at the top at the page and `ISO-8859-1` as encoding in the XML file, I have checked the file so it’s valid ISO-8859-1. I don’t have access to the server I am sending this data to, but I fixed it in a VB6 program which use the same logic with:

```
aPostBody = StrConv(strBody, vbFromUnicode)
WinHttpReq.SetTimeouts 100000, 100000, 100000, 1000000
WinHttpReq.Send aPostBody
```

And in a C# program that also uses the same logic with

```
// ISO-8859-1
byte[] bytes = Encoding.GetEncoding(28591).GetBytes(data);
```

But in ASP classic I need some help to find a way to change the encoding on a string to ISO-8859-1.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
Session.CodePage = 28591
```

There is some good information [here](http://devlibrary.businessobjects.com/BusinessObjectsXIR2/en/en/RAS_SDK/rassdk_com_doc/doc/rassdk_com_doc/BestPractices11.html), and I got the CodePage number [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/287946).

Comment: Too bad I can't upvote twice. This same answer solved another issue for me thanks to the first link.

Comment: This fixed my german encoding... combined with charset: Response.Charset = "utf-8"

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried using [Response.Charset](http://www.w3schools.com/ASP/prop_charset.asp)  and setting it like so:

```
<% Response.Charset="ISO-8859-1"%>
```

Answer (score 2):

Check the encoding of the .ASP file and all the .ASP files included with `#include`.

Once I had a problem when I created a new .ASP file in VS and was encoding in UTF-8. This file was included by others, and the file encoding "overwrites" all other encoding commands.

Comment: This was my issue, pay attention to this answer.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK this is a known problem with WinHttpReq / XMLHTTPRequest, hope someone proves me wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the `meta` tag equivalent to what you are doing?

Example:

```
Response.Write("<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1' />")
```

Note: I use a `Response.Write` to paste spit out the charset, because Visual Studio will attempt to save the file with a different encoding if, for example, the charset is UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

Reference this as well: [How do I set the character set using XMLHttp Object for a POST in classic ASP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190988/how-do-i-set-the-character-set-using-xmlhttp-object-for-a-post-in-classic-asp)

Answer (score 0):

I have used this component both on ASP and Javascript, but on javascript I found the resolution for this issue here: http://squio.nl/blog/2006/06/27/xmlhttprequest-and-character-encoding/

Answer (score 0):

The solution:

```
Response.AddHeader "Content-Type", "text/html;charset=UTF-8"
Response.CodePage = 65001
Response.CharSet = "UTF-8
```

Complete:
https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/80886/encoding-asp-cl%C3%A1ssico/81418#81418